# Downloading file from local storage

Tags: javascript, html

is anyone aware how to properly "exploit" the local browser storage to "cache" chunks of data, assemble them and prompt a download?

I'm currently using the method where data is stored encoded in `B64`, and passed to an `<a>` element constructed on the fly and the target set to a `data URI`; I don't feel like this is the right method in case of big files (>5Mb) and not tested it so far.

I'm also aware that Mega does something similar, but it's unclear to me how they do it and how to properly recreate that.

In case anyone is wondering, the data is transferred via websocket to the browser.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @epascarello this is local filesystem access, which as stated in the article is not part of the standard and partially supported only by chrome (which could drop it at any moment)

Comment: If I remember right, Mega does use that in chrome. Been awhile since I looked at it and too busy to look now.